# window.onload in Microsoft Edge and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, onload, microsoft-edge

I have a script that draws graphs on some of my pages. The graphs are pretty slow to load, so I want the rest of the page to show up first, and then to call the javascript to create the graphs after that, so that the user is not waiting very long for the whole page, just for the graphs. I'm using

```
window.onload = function(){....};
```

for this, and it works fine in Chrome and Firefox. However, in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer, the page takes a long time to load, and then shows up with the graphs already there. I added a breakpoint to the graph script and realized that the script is being called before the page is loaded--so, the opposite of what I want it to do. Does `window.onload` not work in these two browsers? If so, is there an alternative function that does the same thing? The only other thing I can think of is delaying the script for a few seconds to let the rest of the page load first, but this seems pretty hackish and I'd rather not do it if there is an alternative.

Comment: The *load* event fires after all content, including images, have loaded. Perhaps you want instead the *DOMContentLoaded* event? `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {...});`?

Comment: @Sampson When I use DOMContentLoaded, the same thing happens--the page takes forever to load, and then the graphs are already there. This is because, while everything is loaded, it hasn't yet been rendered when the script gets called, so everything is still slowed down. I need something that behaves like window.onload does in chrome and firefox, it's just that in microsoft edge and explorer, window.onload happens too early.